# ISO 8859-1 Characters WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: php

is there an ISO 8859-1 Characters WYSIWYG Editor?

I would like to have a text-area with ISO 8859-1 buttons.

Any ideas?

Incorporating ISO 8859-1 characters into a textarea using php and mysql as backend.

Either have buttons so that users can click and insert them or type combination of dead keys and characters.

Comment: You mean with buttons for all the diacritics & non-ASCII characters in iso-8859-1?

Comment: @Michael. Yes exactly please.

Comment: Please make this much more clear. What do you mean by "WYSIWYG editor" exactly? What should it do? Where do the characters need to be inserted?

Comment: Sorry trying to get a hang of things here. I want to have an international character with a combination of a dead key and a character. eg. `+a = &#224;. I am using php/mysql

Comment: why don't you use utf8? you'll be able to represent way more characters and you don't have problems when the client is using a different iso-8859-* encoding

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want to create an input method for characters that aren't on the user's keyboard?

Comment: I need a way for the client to type a different iso-8859 using standard international keyboard.

Comment: I don't think this is what you want (as it's a clickable keyboard) but it's at least related: http://www.ajaxblender.com/jquery-virtual-keyboard.html

Comment: @Pekka YOU ARE SO RIGHT. Please how can I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: @Pekka. It is related but would like to have just for ISO 8859-1 Characters only. i just want users to insert/type these characters in a user friendly manner.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, I gather you want to create an input method for characters that aren't on the user's keyboard.

- For a mouse-clicking approach, there is the [jQuery virtual keyboard](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard). It can switch between lots and lots of keyboard layouts. This is  the easiest option because it's a ready-to-use product.
- A key-binding approach (specific key combinations leading to specific special characters) I expect you would have to build yourself, but maybe the [jQuery hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) can be of some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: from the above comments I think that my suggestion is not as relevant as Pekkas.*

`htmlentities()`
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

There is a popular editor you can apply to textareas of html-forms. 
 CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/

Keep in mind and investigate their licensing, though. at their download section you still can download the original FCKeditor

This "editor" converts the input to the corresponding html entities where possible by default.

You should consider to configure a more suitable encoding for the entire project, though. That way you can save and handle the data in its "original" form  with no need to code and recode. This also helps avoiding headaches trying to decode some string that has been converted twice or more times and then saved.

Comment: how can they type these characters for instance? &#211; &#210; in user friendly manner

Comment: As I understand it you just type them and they get converted when submitted. I don't recall if there is a "insert symbol"-kind of tool to insert characters that are not accessible on the keyboard.

Comment: I didn't see the other comments. @Pekka has the better approach to your requirements. What I suggest is only useful to people who have the possibility to type the characters because of their keyboard layout.

Comment: what kind of keyboard layout can type ISO 8859-1 Characters?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1
In the section `Languages with complete coverage` you'll find the languages that use characters that are available through iso 8859.
I, for instance, have an spanish-latinamerican keyboardlayout wich lets me type some of those characters like ó Ö ñ Ñ í. But not the complete set. I can't type directly the german `ß` eventhough it belongs to the same character set. The character set enconding is not the same as the keyboard layout and language.